# Play new css animation seamlessly

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I created a simple HTML game, which disappears under the screen when I click on a moving box.
However, the animation that disappears starts at the original location, not where it was clicked.

I think 0% of the `remove @keyframes` should have the location of the click, but I couldn't find a way

How shall I do it?

```js
  (function () {
    const charactersGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.character');
    const stage = document.querySelector('.stage')
    const clickHandler = (e) => {
      const target = e.target;
      if (target.classList.contains('character')) {
        target.classList.remove(`f${target.dataset.id}`);
        target.classList.add('f0');
        target.classList.add('remove');

        setTimeout(() => { stage.removeChild(target) }, 2000);
      }
    }
    stage.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  }());
```

```css
.stage {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background: #eeeeaa;
      width: 40vw;
      height: 20vw;
    }

    @keyframes moving {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(30vw);
      }
    }
    @keyframes remove {
      0% {
        transform: translate(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateY(60vw);
      }
    }
    .character {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-size: contain;
      animation: moving infinite alternate;
    }
    .remove {
      animation: remove 0.2s cubic-bezier(.68,-0.55,.27,1.55) forwards;
    }
    .f0 {
      background-color: black;
      animation-duration: 2s;
    }
    .f1 {
      left: 5%;
      bottom: 5%;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="stage">
  <div class="character f1" data-id="1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The solution is to animate the position with JS, not CSS. CSS animations aren't made for the context you're using them in. You could also wrap f1 in another container that gets positioned by the click though. But in the long run you'll want to give coordinates to f1, display it where those coordinates point to and handle all calculations yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the first animation to consider `left` instead of translate then append both of them to the element initially and you simply toggle the `animation-play-state` when adding the `remove` class

```js
(function() {
  const charactersGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.character');
  const stage = document.querySelector('.stage')
  const clickHandler = (e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    if (target.classList.contains('character')) {
      target.classList.add('remove');

      setTimeout(() => {
        stage.removeChild(target)
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
  stage.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}());
```

```css
.stage {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: #eeeeaa;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 20vw;
}

@keyframes moving {
  100% {
    left:calc(95% - 50px);
  }
}

@keyframes remove {
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-30vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(60vw);
  }
}

.character {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background:red;
  left: 5%;
  bottom: 5%;
  animation: 
     moving 2s infinite alternate,
     remove 1s cubic-bezier(.68, -0.55, .27, 1.55) forwards paused;
}

.remove {
  animation-play-state:paused,running;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="stage">
  <div class="character f1" data-id="1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is really cool. One doubt here, when we add the remove class, our moving animation gets overridden by the remove one ? Because we didn't explicitly remove it.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur no animation will get removed which is the key here. I will simply pause the moving one and run the remove one. It's a pause/play and not an add/remove

Answer (score 2):

If your use case is to deal with a lot of such boxes and complexity, it's better to go with handling everything with pure JS but I tried to make this work with minimal changes in JS and CSS.

I have added comments to the new JS lines.

Also taken the liberty to have a separate class with name `moving` for animation `moving` so that we can remove it on click.

```js
(function () {
    const charactersGroup = document.querySelectorAll('.character');
    const stage = document.querySelector('.stage')
    const clickHandler = (e) => {
      const target = e.target;
      if (target.classList.contains('character')) {
        target.classList.remove(`f${target.dataset.id}`);
        target.classList.add('f0');
        // remove the moving animation
        target.classList.remove('moving');
        // Get offsetWidth which is the half of width to substract later while calculating left for the target i.e our box.
        const offsetWidth  = parseInt(getComputedStyle(target).width)/2;
        // e.clientX gives us the x coordinate of the mouse pointer
        // target.getBoundingClientRect().left gives us left position of the bounding rectangle and acts as a good offset to get the accurate left for our box.
        target.style.left = `${e.clientX -target.getBoundingClientRect().left - offsetWidth}px`;
       target.classList.add('remove');
     setTimeout(() => { stage.removeChild(target) }, 2000);
      } 
    }
    stage.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  }());
```

```css
.stage {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      background: #eeeeaa;
      width: 40vw;
      height: 20vw;
    }

    @keyframes moving {
      0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateX(30vw);
      }
    }
    @keyframes remove {
      0% {
        transform: translate(0vh);
      }
      100% {
        transform: translateY(60vw);
      }
    }
    .character {
      position: absolute;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-size: contain;
    }
    
    .moving{
      animation: moving infinite alternate;
    }
    .remove {
      animation: remove 0.2s cubic-bezier(.68,-0.55,.27,1.55) forwards;
    }
    .f0 {
      background-color: black;
      animation-duration: 2s;
    }
    .f1 {
      left: 5%;
      bottom: 5%;
      animation-duration: 2s;
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<div class="stage">
  <div class="character moving f1" data-id="1"></div>
</div>
```